# How to optimize nonlinear funtion with some constraint in c++

Tags: c++, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find a variable in C++ that allows a given nonlinear formula to have a maximum value in a constraint.

It is to calculate the maximum value of the formula below in the given constraint in C++.
You can also use the library.(e.g. Nlopt)

- formula : ln(1+a*x+b*y+c*z)
- a, b, c are numbers input by the user
- x, y, z are variables to be derived
- variable constraint is that x, y, z are positive and x+y+z<=1

Comment: To answer your question "Is it possible", yes.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be transformed into a linear optimization problem.

`max ln(1+ax+by+cz) <--> max (ax+by+cz) s.t. ax+by+cz > -1`

This means that it is a linear optimization problem (with one more constraint) that you can easily handle with whatever C++ methods together with your Convex Optimization knowledge.

**Reminders to write a good code**:

- Check the validity of input value.
- Since the input value can be negative, you need to consider this circumstance which can yield different results.

> P.S.
>
> - This problem seems to be **Off Topic** on SO.
> - If it is your homework, it is for your own good to write the code yourself. Besides, we do not have enough time to write that for you.
> - This should have been a comment if I had more *reputation*.